# Port requirements for System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory

Tags: c#, active-directory, port, directoryservices

We have a product which implements role based authentication using AD.
At the start of this application, it tries to enumerate through all the domains in the current forest to fetch some information which will be used later.
A snippet of the code is shown below

```
Domain currentDomain = Domain.GetDomain(new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.Domain));
Forest currentForest = currentDomain.Forest;
string forestName = currentForest.Name;
foreach (Domain domain in currentForest.Domains)
{
     //processing code.
}
```

The  above code runs fine until 3rd statement and the forestName variable is initialized properly with the current forest name.
But it fails in the foreach loop when it tries to execute **currentForest.Domains**

We are getting an ActiveDirectoryServerDownException with the error message "The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted" with an error code 1355.
From the below link, I got to know that this could be a dns misconfiguration or the ports might be blocked by firewall.
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/msonline/en-US/53804e9d-ccdd-450a-967b-b7e8f67cddae/active-directory-error-code-1355?forum=winserverDS
I am trying to understand the ports that need to be open for communication on server machine(Active directory server) and client machine.
The below link specifies so many number of ports which confused me.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/832017/service-overview-and-network-port-requirements-for-windows 
Can some one provide me information on what are the ports that are required to be open on server and client machines so that I can successfully enumerate all the domains in the forest.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Those methods use the LDAP protocol to talk to AD, which is all over port 389.

Just to be sure, I ran your code and watched the network connections it used, and it only used port 389.

As a side note, you can simplify your code a little by using [`Forest.GetCurrentForest()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.forest.getcurrentforest) instead of looking up the current domain then looking up the forest for that domain.

```
Forest currentForest = Forest.GetCurrentForest();
```

Either way will get the same job done.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This port 389 is in the client machine right. So, the machine on which this code is running should have the port 389 white listed or unblocked. Please confirm

Comment: Technically, it's port 389 on the target computer (the domain controller), but yes, the client machine will have to have target port 389 unblocked if it has a local firewall. Also, any firewall along the network path will have to allow it.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Just got to know that the IT team is asking to use secure port (636) instead of unsecure port(389). Google is not giving me any satisfactory answers.  Do you have any info on how to get this code work using secure port(636) ?